# How can I get the history of a listing from a RETS server?

Tags: rets

I'm working on a real estate application, and I need to implement a feature that displays the history of changes for a listing. The application interacts with a RETS server to fetch listing data, but I'm unsure about the best approach to retrieve the history information.

I have successfully connected to the RETS server and can fetch basic listing details such as property information, price, and location. However, I now need to access the historical changes made to a specific listing, such as price updates, status changes, and other modifications.

I'm wondering if there is a standard way to retrieve the history of a listing from a RETS server. Are there any specific RETS resources or methods that I should be using? Alternatively, is there a workaround or additional setup required to access historical changes?

Any guidance, code examples, or pointers to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Some RETS Servers provide Historical/HotSheet records as a separate resource. First check if you have access to such data from the feed.
If not, you need to store the historical data from the day starting data pulling. All the changes of a property should be stored based on ModificationTimestamp and process the data based on your needs.